# Python error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, dpkg

I was trying to install "python-sklearn" which requires few dependencies when i try to install any python packages it shows errors something like this. I have tried few solutions suggested by few prevoius post but nothing is working in my case how can I solve this.

```
root@famous-breath:/home# sudo sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up libblas3 (1.2.20110419-7) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3 to provide /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (libblas.so.3) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link `/etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libblas3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblapack3:
 liblapack3 depends on libblas3 | libblas.so.3; however:
  Package libblas3 is not configured yet.
  Package libblas.so.3 is not installed.
  Package libblas3 which provides libblas.so.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblapack3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-numpy:
 python-numpy depends on libblas3 | libblas.so.3; however:
  Package libblas3 is not configured yet.
  Package libblas.so.3 is not installed.
  Package libblas3 which provides libblas.so.3 is not configured yet.
 python-numpy depends on liblapack3 | liblapack.so.3; however:
  Package liblapack3 is not configured yet.
  Package liblapack.so.3 is not installed.
  Package liblapack3 which provides liblapack.so.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-numpy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libblas3
 liblapack3
 python-numpy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@famous-breath:/home#
```

I tried to uninstall libblas3, liblapack3 with apt but when ever I add new package its ended with a error code 1 and list will shows that package

example:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libblas3
 liblapack3
 python-numpy
 python-matplotlib
 python-scipy
 python-sklearn-lib
 python-sklearn
```

Please help How can I solve this..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an issue with python-faraday.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
faraday
python-faraday
```

So I looked for the files associated with it:

```
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i faraday    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   57089 Jun 30 09:49 faraday.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65393 Jun 11 09:39 faraday.md5sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1968 Jun 11 09:39 faraday.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     631 Jun 11 09:39 faraday.postrm`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     592 Jun 11 09:39 faraday.prerm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16980 Jun 30 09:45 python3-faraday-plugins.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17054 Jun  8 14:56 python3-faraday-plugins.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     271 Jun  8 14:56 python3-faraday-plugins.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     420 Jun  8 14:56 python3-faraday-plugins.prerm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     334 Jun 30 13:38 python-faraday.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     387 Jun 11 09:39 python-faraday.md5sums
```

Now all I needed to do was to remove these files:

```
 sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/polar-bookshelf.* /tmp
```

Use the sudo apt update and then you should be able to install software as usual.

Answer (score 0):

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
libblas3
nliblapack3
python-numpy
python-matplotlib
python-scipy
python-sklearn-lib
python-sklearn
```

try this code snipet, it is work fine for me!

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libblas3.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/libblas3.postinst.backup
```

and

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/nliblapack3.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/nliblapack3.postinst.backup
```

do the same for all error causing modules.

after you try to update the cache using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly your locales are not set up correctly. Try running the following command:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

and then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix the problems with your packages.